# which solution is better in terms of space.time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, time-complexity, hashtable, memory-efficient

i have 2 lists of integers. they are both sorted already. I want to find the elements (one from each list) that add up to a given number.

-first idea is to iterate over first list and use binary search to look for the number needed to sum to the given number. i know this will take nlogn time.

the other is to store one of the lists in a hashtable/map (i dont really know the difference) and iterate over other list and look up the needed value. does this take n time? and n memory?

overall which would be better?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing it right. But both has different aspects. Hashing is not a good choice if you have memory constraints. But if you have plenty of memory then yes, you can afford to do that.

Also you will see many times in Computer Science the notion of space-time tradeoff. It will always be some gain by losing some. Hashing runs in O(n) and space complexity is `O(n)`. But in case of searching only `O(nlogn)` time complexity but space complexity is `O(1)`

Long story short, scenario lets you decide which one to select. I have shown just one aspect. There can be many. Know the constraints and tradeoffs of each and you will be able to decide it.

#### A better solution : (Time complexity: `O(n)` Space complexity: `O(1)`)

Suppose there are 2 array `a` and `b`.
Now WLOG suppose `a` is sorted in ascending and another in descending (Even if it is not the case we can traverse it accordingly).

```
  index1=0;index2=0; // considered  0 indexing
  while(index1 <= N1-1 && index2 <= N2-1)
  {
    if ((a[index1] + b[index2]) == x)
        // success
    else if ((a[index1] + b[index2]) > x)
        index2++;
    else
        index1++;
   }
   //failure no such element.
```

Comment: Yes..2 pointer algorithm..do you think I should post that here? @MBo

Comment: Accidentally deleted: In addition - there is also linear algorithm with O(1) memory

Comment: @MBo.: I can post that too...but I avoided it as the OP asked for a general approach toward this kind of analysis..I will add that..thanks for poiting out

Comment: Yes, question is about general approach, about reasonable choice in uncertain conditions, so your answer about trade-off is quite perfect. I am not sure that author really needs two-pointer algo, but it is worth to mention about it.

Comment: @MBo.: Thanks...I will be glad to do that

Comment: @MBo.: I have added it.

Comment: @Ryan♦.: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sort list A in ascending order, and list B in descending order. Set a = 1 and b = 1.

1. If A[a] + B[b] = T, record the pair, increment a, and repeat.
2. Otherwise, A[a] + B[b] < T, increment a, and repeat from 1.
3. Otherwise, A[a] + B[b] > T, increment b, and repeat from 1.
4. Naturally, if a or b exceeds the size of A or B, respectively, terminate.

Example:

```
A = 1, 2, 2, 6, 8, 10, 11
B = 9, 8, 4, 3, 1, 1
T = 10

a = 1, b = 1
A[a] + B[b] = A[1] + B[1] = 10; record; a = a + 1 = 2; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[2] + B[1] = 11; b = b + 1 = 2; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[2] + B[2] = 10; record; a = a + 1 = 3; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[3] + B[2] = 10; record; a = a + 1 = 4; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[4] + B[2] = 14; b = b + 1 = 3; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[4] + B[3] = 10; record; a = a + 1 = 5; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[5] + B[3] = 12; b = b + 1 = 4; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[5] + B[4] = 11; b = b + 1 = 5; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[5] + B[5] = 9; a = a + 1 = 6; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[6] + B[5] = 11; b = b + 1 = 6; repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = A[6] + B[6] = 11; b = b + 1 = 7; repeat.
Terminate.
```

You can do this without additional space if instead of having B sorted in descending order, you set b = |B| and decrement it instead of incrementing it, effectively reading it backwards.

The above procedure misses out on some duplicate answers where B has a string of duplicate values, for instance:

```
A = 2, 2, 2
B = 8, 8, 8
```

The algorithm as described above will yield three pairs, but you might want nine. This can be fixed by detecting this case, keeping separate counters ca and cb for the lengths of the runs of A[a] and B[b] you have seen, and adding ca * cb - ca copies of the last pair you added to the bag. In this example:

```
A = 2, 2, 2
B = 8, 8, 8
a = 1, b = 1
ca = 0, cb = 0
A[a] + B[b] = 10; record pair, a = a + 1 = 2, ca = ca + 1 = 2, repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = 10; record pair, a = a + 1 = 3, ca = ca + 1 = 2, repeat.
A[a] + B[b] = 10; record pair, a = a + 1 = 4;
                  a exceeds bounds, value of A[a] changed;
                  increment b to count run of B's;
                  b = b + 1 = 2, cb = cb + 1 = 2
                  b = b + 1 = 3, cb = cb + 1 = 3
                  b = b + 1 = 4;
                  b exceeds bounds, value of B[b] changed;
                  add ca * cb - ca = 3 * 3 - 3 = 6 copies of pair (2, 8).
```